# How to club every 'n' rows in a dataframe and store it in a new dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to sum every 15 rows and there are a total of 7200 rows and store it in a new dataframe. This is the approach I have tried and it works, I would like to know if there is a better panda way of doing it, and it felt slow.

The database looks similar to this:

```
H+M      H         M    S     A - no    W-no A-NLRI W-NLRI   Mean AS PATH   

2355.0  23.0    55.0    15.0    44.0    5.0  90.0   21.0     6.0    
2356.0  23.0    56.0    13.0    21.0    1.0  39.0   1.0      6.0
```

This is the code, the main logic is to create a copy of `df` and overwrite in it using 2 `for` loops and then copy that to the new dataframe, and I wanted to do it for a slice of columns.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("someFile.csv")

#created a copy of df for overwriting purpose
copy_df = df.copy()

# start is to keep track of starting index after every 15th row
start = 0
for i in range(480):
    end = 15*(i+1)

    # This for loop is to iterate over every 15 rows.
    for j in range(start, end+1):

        copy_df.loc[i,'A - no':'Mean AS PATH']+=copy_df.loc[j,'A - no':'Mean AS PATH']

    start = end

#I create a new DataFrame with index and same column names as original df. 
new_df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.RangeIndex(0,480),columns=df.columns)

#Here I copy that part of the dataframe to the "new_df".
new_df = copy_df[:480]
```

Is there a way of directly storing it in "new_df" without first overwriting it in "copy_df"?

Thanks for your help.
It is my first question here. Sorry for the bad formatting.

Edit 1- I added comments to code and tried to explain my approach.

Comment: Explain your logic, don't just paste your code and expect people to go through it and extract the logic themself. Typical [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), don't ask about why your solution is not working, ask about how to solve your problem

Comment: Maybe `df.groupby(df.index//15).sum()`?

Comment: to add onto @HenryYik comment I would store all your dataframes in a container like a dictionary i.e - `{num : dataframe.sum() for num,dataframe in df.groupby(df.index // 15)}`

Comment: @HenryYik thanks, it solves my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have better parametrized code, I defined the following variables:

```
nRows = df.index.size      # How many rows
chunk = 15                 # Chunk size
nChunks = nRows // chunk   # How many chunks
```

Of course, the above code must be executed after *df* has been created,
once, before both tests (of your code and mine).

I also reworked a little your code, changing it also into a function:

```
def f1():
    copy_df = df.copy()
    start = 0
    for i in range(nChunks):
        end = chunk * (i + 1)
        for j in range(start + 1, end):
            copy_df.loc[start, 'A - no':'Mean AS PATH'] += copy_df.loc[j, 'A - no':'Mean AS PATH']
        start = end
    return copy_df[::chunk].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Take a look at the above code and notice that I corrected some flaws in
your original code:

- I removed *count* - an unused variable and its incrementation.
- I removed *try* block.
- *for j in...* loop runs between *start + 1* (inclusive) and *end*
  (exclusive) and the target row is *start*. The aim is to add values
  from "next" rows in the current chunk to the first row, of this
  chunk. Your code actually added **all** rows in a chunk to row
  number *i*, so its value was actually "unnecessarily added" to
  the sum of the chunk.
- I also changed the way how the result is returned (only starting row
  from each chunk, where values were aggregated).
- Your code unnecessarily creates *new_df* as an empty DataFrame,
  because in a moment it is created **again** as a view on first
  rows of *copy_df*.

My, more *pandasonic* code (also as a function) is significantly shorter:

```
def f2():
    return df.loc[:, 'A - no':'Mean AS PATH'].groupby(
        np.arange(len(df.index)) // chunk).sum()\
        .join(df.loc[::chunk, 'H+M':'S'].reset_index(drop=True))
```

To test both functions, I created the source DataFrame as:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1, 7200 * 4 + 1).reshape(-1, 4),
    columns=['A - no', 'Mean AS PATH', 'H+M', 'S'])
```

This DataFrame contains 2 columns from your first range (to sum up) and also
2 columns from the second range (to copy from the first row in the chunk).

Comparison of the execution time (using *%timeit*) is:

- your code (improved by me): 9.05 s,
- my code: 160 ms (56 times faster).